# PHP not parsing HTTP POST (compressed) JSON request?

Tags: php, json, http

I have the following PHP file:

```
<?php
    // ***************************************************
    if (!function_exists('gzdecode'))
    {
        function gzdecode($data) 
        {
            // strip header and footer and inflate
            return gzinflate(substr($data, 10, -8));
        }
    }
    // ***************************************************

    // get compressed (gzip) POST request into a string
    $comprReq = file_get_contents('php://input');

    // get decompressed POST request
    $decomprReq = gzdecode($comprReq);

    // decode to json
    $jsonData = json_decode($decomprReq, true);

    // create file if not exits or open file if exists
    $file = fopen('omni.json', 'a');

    if ($jsonData === null)
    {
        // mark as invalid and save. send HTTP response
        fwrite($file, 'invalid json');
        fclose($file);
        header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    }
    else 
    {
        // write json and save. send HTTP response
        fwrite($file, $jsonData);
        fclose($file);
        header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');          
    }
?>
```

The idea is that it accepts a JSON HTTP POST (compressed - gzipped), decompresses it, and appends the json (in JSON format) at the end of a new (if not exists) or existing json file. It should also send back a 200 OK or 400 BAD REQUEST HTTP response code depending on the outcome.

I try to test this with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) by sending the following:

Headers (note the gzip key):
[image]

Sample JSON body:
[image]

The result:
[image]

Yeap, nothing happens. No JSON file gets created on the server. Response is always 200 OK.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check your permission in server and file path. It's posible that apache cannot have permission to create files.

Comment: Just did, looks OK. I also tried creating omni.json myself (empty) so PHP can just open and write in it without having to create it.

Comment: Can you check if any of the used functions fopen() or fwrite() returns false?

Comment: You create the file with your user permission and if apache try to append some text it's posible that don't have permissions. use chmod 777 omni.json

Answer (score 0):

Check your file path and permission (use `__DIR__` for specify complete path to your filename ). The variable $decomprReq is false, because you send the content in clear text and not gziped. $comprReq have the json values that you send. I test your code and looks ok.

Comment: actually permissions were fine. problem was the code (e.g. comment lines with no closing slash, e.g. /**** with no */)

Comment: In the code I see // *** that is different from //** .